# How do I download an mp3 file with Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to download some playlists off soundcloud and found a site that does this for you. Of course if the playlist is long, then it's super tedious to click each link to download. So I saved the HTML of the page and have parsed out the links. The idea is to use urllib or requests to download the files.

Here's my code:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

track_url = 'https://scdownloader.io/download?track=zandex-hazerback-erox-stroke-bth-release&token=be1bc7997695495f756312886f566110'
track_name = 'BANG_THE_HOUSE___zandex-hazerback-erox-stroke-bth-release.mp3'
output_file = '/Users/ms/Desktop/playlist/{}'.format(track_name)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(track_url, output_file)
```

When I run the above code, it does save the file, but it arrives as a 1 byte file only.

I've tried other permutations using requests but basically either it doesn't work, downloads and saves a zero byte file, or does work to download and save a 1 byte file... just can't get the whole thing!

Also note, I have to send headers b/c otherwise I get a 403 error.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

EDIT:

Per the comments below, here's what the urlretrieve http response is:

```
Date: Fri, 15 Mar 2019 23:52:44 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dcc5f95391fac83973cc77648c0e8c0391552693964; expires=Sat, 14-Mar-20 23:52:44 GMT; path=/; domain=.scdownloader.io; HttpOnly; Secure
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.36
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=fsnrrrtpnrav3vq5u2t9vfvrp7; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 4b82671d38067790-LAX
```

Comment: Have you checked the messages returned by `urlretrieve`?

Comment: My apologies, I don't know how to check the messages returned by urlretrieve. I did search for some examples on google and didn't come up with anything. I just tried wrapping in a try/except and nothing came back. Grateful for any advice. Thank you.

Comment: What does `print(urllib.request.urlretrieve(track_url, output_file))` show?

Comment: ('/Users/ms/Desktop/playlist/BANG_THE_HOUSE___zandex-hazerback-erox-stroke-bth-release.mp3', <http.client.HTTPMessage object at 0x10f80b828>)

Comment: As I suspected, if you simply open `track_url` in a browser, you will get a single space character, not the track that you are looking for. The site probably requires authentication that you do not do in your script.

Comment: The site doesn't require authentication, you can literally paste that url into a browser and it should download. I'm going to edit the original to show you what the http object message is.

Comment: I did just that: pasted the URL and got a single-character text file.

Comment: There might be a time limit where the urls are good. I just tried the same, pasting in the URL and it failed, when earlier I did the same and it worked fine. Here's the playlist I'm trying to grab: https://soundcloud.com/h-celine-2/sets/bass-house and the website is: https://scdownloader.io/ 

Of course I don't want to trouble you and you've been awesome already, I can just do this manually one at a time.

Comment: I think this question should be renamed "How do I download an mp3 file *from Soundcloud* with Python3".

Comment: Also the website that OP is using to download mp3 files doesn't work anymore so it may be impossible to answer this question exactly.